# Right way to use fontawesome with angular 4 projects

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I want to use fontawesome in my angular4 projects. I use like below

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

In

```
style.scss
$fa-font-path: "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
```

When i do ng serve it works fine. But in production build, font awesome icons are not shown in IE. How do i fix this issue or what is the correct way install and configure font awesome.

Answer (score 0):

install the font-awesome library and add the dependency to package.json...

**Using CSS**

To add Font Awesome CSS icons to your app add following configuration in `angular-cli.json`

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
]
```

**Using SASS**

Create an empty file `_variables.scss in src/.`

Add the following to `_variables.scss:`

```
$fa-font-path : '../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts';
```

In `styles.scss` add the following:

```
@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

Comment: IE which version?

Comment: If still not working you can go to IE settings and enable Please check for Allow font downloads https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/threat-protection/block-untrusted-fonts-in-enterprise#Turn_on_and_use_the_Blocking_untrusted_fonts_feature this link for tutorial

Comment: Trying it now. Just wondering for sass how is your solution different than the one i am using. Looks to be same. I am using IE 11 version

Comment: path is diffrent `@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';`

Comment: ~ will directly point to node modules, its a short cut. Let me try by removing scss.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162650/discussion-between-santosh-singh-and-hacker).

Comment: After making changes just reset the IE settings

Comment: FYI. I directly included fontawesome cdn link in index page and removed the nodes modules way. It works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on angular-cli project then remove the comments from `polyfills.ts` file can resolve the issue.

- Remove the comment from polyfills.ts with the title:
  **/**IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills.**/**
- Also add Font Awesome CSS file in angular-cli.json

`"styles": [
      "styles.css",
      "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
    ]`

Comment: Does it work in IE ?? This did not work for me earlier. Can you confirm that this worked for u.

Comment: Yes it worked for me in this way. I also again implement this just now to confirm and it worked. Just add the appropriate css file in **.angular-cli.json** under **styles** and import the modules required by IE9,IE10 and IE11 in **polyfills.ts**

Comment: I am using sass